# How to join the data from 2 tables without any relationships in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I currently have 2 tables no established relationships between the two. I just like to append the data from the 2nd table to the end of the 1st table in the JSON output.

1st table:

```
 map_type      map_value  
 -----------------------------
 image_link    www.google.com
 top_lat       32.91
 right_long    -117.13
 zoom_level    17.5
```

2nd table:

```
 marker_name  marker_lat  marker_long 
 ------------------------------------------
 Food         32.91       -117.14    
 Party        31.22       -119.20
 Chips        29.02       -120.00
```

I understand the basic query to join 2 tables, and implemented using the following code:

```
$sql = "select * from second_table join first_table";

$q = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));

//create an array
$jsonData = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q))
{
    $jsonData[$row['map_type']] = $row['map_value'];

    // Issue is here
    if ( !isset($jsonData['markers'] ) )
    {
        $jsonData['markers'] = array();

    }
    array_push($jsonData['markers'],
               array('marker_name'=> $row['marker_name'],
                     'marker_lat'=> $row['marker_lat'], 'marker_long'=> $row['marker_long']));

}

echo json_encode($jsonData);
```

As such, I get the following output:

```
{
    "image_link": "www.google.com",
    "markers": [{
        "marker_name": "Food",
        "marker_lat": "32.91",
        "marker_long": "-117.14"
    }, {
        "marker_name": "Food",
        "marker_lat": "32.91",
        "marker_long": "-117.14"
    },
    ...
    }],
    "top_lat": "32.91",
    "right_long": "-117.13",
    "zoom_level": "17.5"
}
```

The only data from the second table is the data contained in `markers`, while the other field data is from the first table.

The problem is in the comment labeled "Issue is here". **Each** marker entry in the second table is repeated **4 times**, where **4** represents the number of fields in the first table.

I know I'm doing something wrong in that area, but I just started learning and trying to understand php better.

The output should look something like, where `markers` is appended to the end of the list, with the correct number of entries:

```
{
    "image_link": "www.google.com",
    "top_lat": "32.91",
    "right_long": "-117.13",
    "zoom_level": "17.5",
    "markers": [{
        "marker_name": "Food",
        "marker_lat": "32.91",
        "marker_long": "-117.14"
    }, {
        "marker_name": "Party",
        "marker_lat": "31.22",
        "marker_long": "-119.20"
    }, {
        "marker_name": "Chips",
        "marker_lat": "29.02",
        "marker_long": "-120.00"
    }]
}
```

How can I achieve this output?

**UPDATE**: as @sepehr has explained, I understand the cause now and have replaced the code with the following to make 2 queries:

```
$sql = "select * from first_table";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));

$jsonData = array();

while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $jsonData[$row['map_type']] = $value;
}

$sql = "select * from second_table";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));

$index = 1;

while($rownew =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $markers[$index] = array("marker_name" => $rownew['marker_name'], "marker_lat" => doubleval($rownew['marker_lat']), "marker_long" => doubleval($rownew['marker_long']) );

    ++$index;
}

$jsonData['markers'] = $markers;
echo json_encode ($jsonData);
```

This achieves the correct output, but can someone let me know if this is the most efficient and optimal way?

Comment: Why you want to do that ?? 
The position of array key does not master in PHP.

Comment: just try putting ` // Issue is here
    if ( !isset($jsonData['markers'] ) )
    {
        $jsonData['markers'] = array();

    }
    array_push($jsonData['markers'],
               array('marker_name'=> $row['marker_name'],
                     'marker_lat'=> $row['marker_lat'], 'marker_long'=> $row['marker_long']));

}` insisde the `if ( !isset($jsonData['markers'] ) )`

Comment: That `JOIN` doesn't make any sense. You need an `ON` clause or you'll get a cross-product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those duplicates are because of that `JOIN` statement. It will produce duplicate rows. [Have a look](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f61bb/3) for yourself.

[image: duplicate records]

In order to build that json object, I suggest you executing two separate queries on those tables. Since they have no logical relation with each other.

Or if you MUST achieve this in one query, which I don't recommend, [use a `UNION` like this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f61bb/8) to avoid those duplicate records.

Comment: thank you for the illustration and explanation, I updated my code with new implementation using 2 queries and it produced the correct output...however I like to ask if you can see if its most optimal and efficient?

Comment: No, it's not the most efficient way to do this. You have two nested `while`s in your updated code. It means that per each record in the first result set you're querying the second table for its all records. If the first table has 4 records, for example, you're executing 5 queries, overwriting the `$markers` array again and again. The most efficient way to do this is to use two separate queries/loops, one for the first table, and one for the second table. Then you just add the `$markers` array into the first result set.

Comment: followed your suggestion and updated, can you please verify now?

Comment: Well done! Looks good to me now. Just a few notes: On line **8**, `$value` is undefined; you mean `$row['map_value']`, right? Second note; you don't need to keep track of `$index` in the second loop, just append to the array like this: `$markers[] = [...]`.

Comment: copy-paste error :)...thanks for your suggestions and help...fixed...upvoted and marked as answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Get the results from the 2 tables separately and merge them using the `array_merge` function.

```
$maps = array(); //get the result from table 1
$markers = array(); //get the result from table 2

$result = array_merge($maps,$markers);

echo json_encode($result);
```